# I can't play sound in my wpf app with an asset

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

I'm fairly new to programming and can't seem to get over an issue. Basically, I'm making a game in wpf and want to add sound effects. Unfortunately I can't find out how to do that. I managed to make the sound play from file from my computer but since I want to share it later I must make an asset for the sound. I keep getting errors when I use .MediaFailed often an error that says the asset could not be found but I get another issue when the Uri of the MediaPlayer is

```
@"pack://application:,,,/Sounds/one_beep.mp3"
```

it gives a System.NotSupportedException.

Anyways, my questions are:

1. How do I play audio in wpf with assets? (answered)
2. Why does the issues I runed on happened?

Now that the thing works, I want to know why it works and not earlier. Here's a tutorial on how to do the reproduction:

1. Create a wpf app in visual studio
2. create a button in the main window .xaml and assign click to a function
3. insert a mp3 file into the project mark it as content
4. make a MediaPlayer object in the .xaml.cs and play the mp3 in the click function

If you did it like  did you should not hear the sound. Here's my code (I can confirm it runs):

```
MediaPlayer player = new();

    private void Button_Sound(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        player.Open(new Uri("Assets/one_beep.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
        player.Play();
        player.MediaFailed += (o, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(args.ErrorException);
        };
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The fastest way to get help from other people is to provide an reproducible sample project.

Answer (score 0):

The Media Player is fairly simple.

1. Create it with operator new
2. Hook up an event handler for the MediaFailed event (optional but a good way to diagnose issues)
3. Construct a URI around your media file
4. Call player.Open() with the URI.
5. Play the sound

Here is an example that uses a relative URI

```
var player = new MediaPlayer();
player.MediaFailed += OnMediaFailed;
var uri = new  Uri("Resources/PM_TS_Camera_Film_35mm_SLR_CANON_A1_MKH8040_52_Shutter_Release_1_60th_51.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
player.Open(uri);
player.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
player.Play();
```

Comment: Well that's exactly what I did before but doesn't seem to work for me. Although thanks for the answer with it I found out that i have to put the time span of the MediaPlayer to 0. I still get a System.NotSupportedException!

Comment: Wait, I tried it again by ctrl + c ctrl + v your code snippet and it worked, the only difference I see is the TimeSpan.Zero. This little detail hasn't been said anywhere (well I think because I spent all day long searching for an answer and couldn't find any). EDIT: Another difference is that the uri is var type and not uri type when you initialize it.

Comment: Nvm I checked what happened when I removed the TimeSpan.Zero and it still worked. So I still have no idea why it didn't work earlier

Comment: Once you have played the file once, if you want to play it again with the same player object you first should stop it and first reset the time back to TimeSpan.Zero

Comment: First why does it work in my game (where I use the same MediaPlayer and and don't stop the sound neither set the time span to zero) and not in my reproduction even though I stop the sound and set the time span to zero? I don't want to just continue without knowing why it works.

Comment: The only advice I can give you is to look at the exact error.  If you get an exception, stop it in the debugger when you get it and examine the hell out of the exception fields, message, etc.  Look at the call stack.   Any error codes or specific text in there?  Google them.   Also try setting the  MediaFailed event handler as I described and see if that fires.

Comment: I already tried it out, it lead me to a dead end. Or I didn't traduce well the error, because my native language is French. You can maybe follow the tutorial I made on how to make the error appear and get the actual error message with more google results?